# Items in RecyclerView do remain as it is in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In below image, when user clicks on the item of recyclerview, "ADDED TO WORDS"

[ADDED TO WORDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Pn2.jpg)

But after closing and opening the App again, it changes back to "ADD TO WORDS"

[ADD TO WORDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtMcG.jpg)

I want to keep this same when user reopens the app.

TodayFragment.java

```
public class TodayFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView wordRecyclerView;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private Context mContext;

    WordAdapter mWordAdapter;


    private static final String LOG_TAG = "TodayFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        dbHelper = new DbHelper(mContext);
        mDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onAttach");
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onDetach");
        mContext = null;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today,container,false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        wordRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.word_recycler_view);
       // wordRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        wordRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        String query = "select * from wordhistory;";
        Cursor c = mDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[] {});

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"cursor count, "+c.getCount());

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onViewCreated set recycler view");

        mWordAdapter = new WordAdapter(mContext);


        wordRecyclerView.setAdapter(mWordAdapter);

        mWordAdapter.swapCursor(c);
        mWordAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



    }
}
```

fragment_today.xml

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    tools:context=".fragment.TodayFragment">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/word_recycler_view" />


        </LinearLayout>




</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

WordAdapter.java

```
public class WordAdapter extends BaseCursorAdapter<WordAdapter.WordViewHolder> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "WordAdapter";

    Context mContext;

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    private int touchCount=0;
    Cursor mCursor;


    public WordAdapter(Context mContext) {
        super(null);

        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    public interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(int position);

    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view;
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.word_card_layout,parent,false);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onCreateViewHolder: ");

        return new WordViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(WordViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {

        int wordColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD);
        int defColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_DEFINITION);
        int audioColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_AUDIOURL);
        int synonymColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_SYNONYMS);
        int antonymColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DictionaryContract.DictionaryEntry.COLUMN_WORD_ANTONYMS);

        String wordStr = cursor.getString(wordColumnIndex);
        String wordDefStr = cursor.getString(defColumnIndex);
        String audioStr = cursor.getString(audioColumnIndex);
        String synonymStr = cursor.getString(synonymColumnIndex);
        String antonymStr = cursor.getString(antonymColumnIndex);

        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onBindViewHolder wordStr: "+wordStr);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"onBindViewHolder wordDefStr: "+wordDefStr);

        holder.wordTextView.setText(wordStr);
        holder.defTextView.setText(wordDefStr);
    }

  /*  @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }*/


    @Override
    public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
        super.swapCursor(newCursor);
    }



    public class WordViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView wordTextView;
        ImageView audioImageView;
        TextView defTextView;
        TextView wordTrickTextView;
        TextView defTrickTextView;
        ImageView shareImageView;
        ImageView favUnselectImageView;
        ImageView favSelectImageView;
        TextView addWordTextView;
        TextView addedWordTextView;
        ImageView tickImageView;
        RelativeLayout addWordRelativeLayout;



        public WordViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"WordViewHolder itemView: "+itemView);

            wordTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordText);
            audioImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordAudio);
            defTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordDef);
            wordTrickTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memorisingTrickWord);
            defTrickTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memorisingTrickDef);
            shareImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordShare);
            favUnselectImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordFavUnselect);
            favSelectImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.wordFavSelect);
            addWordTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addWordText);
            addedWordTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addedWordText);
            tickImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tickImage);
            addWordRelativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addWordRelativeLayout);

            addedWordTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tickImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            addWordRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (touchCount==0){
                        addWordTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        addedWordTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tickImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        ((Animatable) tickImageView.getDrawable()).start();
                        touchCount=1;
                    } else{
                        addWordTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        addedWordTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tickImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        ((Animatable) tickImageView.getDrawable()).stop();
                        touchCount=0;
                    }

                }
            });





        }
    }
}
```

User should be able to see those changes they did in any item of recycler view even after reopening the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close an app, the system automatically destroys the activity. Thus when you open it again, the activity is recreated.

You can save data for the activity before the activity is destroyed using `savedInstanceState`.

You need to override the `onSaveInstanceState` method in your activity and add to the bundle. Below is an example code:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle saveInstanceState){
    // example, save if text is added
    saveInstanceState.putBoolean("Herbivore", true); 
    super.onSaveInstanceState(saveInstanceState);
}
```

Then when your activity starts, you can receive the bundle from `OnCreate`.

```
@Override
boolean herbivoreAdded;
public void OnCreate(Bundle onSaveInstanceState){
   super.OnCreate(saveInstanceState);
   // access saved value
   herbivoreAdded = saveInstanceState.getBoolean("Herbivore");
}
```